# Multiple alerts instead of one for single click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am working on a project and encountered a strange problem.

```
<html>
<head><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
<div id="tree" style="height:500px;width:300px;float:left;">
    <script>            

    var JSONObject= {"className":"com.alta.entity.Person","key":"this","modifier":1,"value":"Person [id\u003d1001, firstName\u003dShiju]","level":0,"elementArray":[
        {"className":"java.lang.Long","key":"id","modifier":17,"value":"1001","level":1,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.String","key":"firstName","modifier":17,"value":"Shiju","level":2,"elementArray":[{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"0","modifier":17,"value":"S","level":3,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"1","modifier":17,"value":"h","level":4,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"2","modifier":17,"value":"i","level":5,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"3","modifier":17,"value":"j","level":6,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"4","modifier":17,"value":"u","level":7,"elementArray":[]}]},{"className":"java.util.ArrayList","key":"addressArray","modifier":1,"value":"[com.alta.entity.Address@10045eb]","level":3,"elementArray":[{"className":"com.alta.entity.Address","key":"0","modifier":1,"value":"com.alta.entity.Address@10045eb","level":4,"elementArray":[{"className":"java.lang.Long","key":"id","modifier":17,"value":"1001","level":5,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.String","key":"addressLine","modifier":17,"value":"This is addredss Line","level":6,"elementArray":[{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"0","modifier":17,"value":"T","level":7,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"1","modifier":17,"value":"h","level":8,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"2","modifier":17,"value":"i","level":9,"elementArray":[]},{"className":"java.lang.Character","key":"3","modifier":17,"value":"s","level":10,"elementArray":[]}]}]}]}]};

        var elementList= JSONObject.elementArray;
        var elementContainer=document.createElement('ul');
        var objectArray = new Array();
        function createObjectArray(elementClassName,elementValue,elementId,elementModifier){
            obj=new Object();
            obj.id = elementId;
            obj.className = elementClassName;
            obj.value = elementValue;
            obj.modifier = elementModifier;
            objectArray.push(obj);
        }
        function valuesOnClick(element2){
            /*var element2ID=element2.id;
            var reqID = element2ID[0];*/
            alert("callllllllllllllll -- > "+$(event.target).text());
            //document.getElementById('Class').innerHTML= element2.id.toString();
            /*var id = $(element2).attr('id');
            for (var i=0;objectArray.length;i++){
                if (id===objectArray[i].id){
                    document.getElementById('Class').innerHTML= objectArray[i].className;
                    document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML= objectArray[i].value;
                }
            }*/
        }
        function generateGuid()
            {
                var result, i, j;
                result = '';
                for(j=0; j<32; j++)
                    {
                    if( j == 8 || j == 12|| j == 16|| j == 20)
                        result = result + '-';
                    i = Math.floor(Math.random()*16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
                    result = result + i;
                    }
                return result
            }
        //document.getElementById('tree').appendChild(test(JSONObject));

        /*function load(){
        alert("Looading ...........");
            var element = document.getElementById('tree');

            console.log(createUls(JSONObject));
            element.appendChild(createUls(JSONObject));
        }
        var id = 1;
        function createUls(element){
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            var exLi = document.createElement('li');
            exLi.innerHTML = element.key;
            ul.appendChild(exLi);
            var elementArray = element.elementArray;
            for(var i=0; i<elementArray.length; i++){
                var cElement = elementArray[i];
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.innerHTML = cElement.key;
                if(cElement.elementArray.length > 0){
                    li.appendChild(createUls(cElement));
                }
                ul.appendChild(li);
            } 
            return ul;
        }*/ 
        function createObjectGraph(element){
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var tempID = generateGuid();
            li.setAttribute('id',tempID);
            li.setAttribute('onclick','valuesOnClick()');
            li.innerHTML = element.key;
            ul.appendChild(li);
            createObjectArray(element.className,element.value,tempID,element.modifier);
            var elementArray = element.elementArray;
            var ul2 = document.createElement('ul');
            li.appendChild(createTree(elementArray,ul2));
            return ul;
        }
        function createTree(list,container){
            if(list){
                for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    var tempID = generateGuid();
                    li.setAttribute('id',tempID);
                    li.setAttribute('onclick','valuesOnClick()');
                    li.innerHTML = list[i].key;
                    if (list[i].elementArray.length > 0) {
                        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
                        li.appendChild(ul);
                        var innerElement=list[i].elementArray;
                        createTree(innerElement, ul);
                    }
                    container.appendChild(li);
                }
            }
            return container;
        }
        document.getElementById('tree').appendChild(createObjectGraph(JSONObject));
    </script>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
        Input: <input align ="justify" type="text" id="Class" style="width:400px;"><br>
        Class: <input align ="justify" type="text" id="Class" style="width:400px;"><br>
        Value: <input align ="center" type="text" id="Value" style="width:400px;"><br>          
    </div>
    <br/>
    <hr/>

    <ul>
        <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>thisss
            <ul>
                <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>id</li>
                <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>firstName
                    <ul>
                        <li value ="Value" onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>0</li>
                        <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>1</li>
                        <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>2</li>
                        <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>3</li>
                        <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>4</li>
                        <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>addressArray
                    <ul>
                        <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>0</li>
                        <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>id</li>
                        <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>addressLine
                            <ul>
                                <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>0</li>
                                <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>1</li>
                                <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>2</li>
                                <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>3</li>
                                <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>4</li>
                                <li onclick= 'valuesOnClick(this)'>5</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                           
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>           
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

when i run this code I intend on getting the value for a single li (which i do get) but I get multiple alerts for the same click of event
The code is working and if you want you can try it yourself. Can some one please explain me the problem in the code or a solution to this. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: you **really** need to split out the calling of `valuesOnClick` to a separate function rather than use inline `onclick`, almost as much as you need to split out inline styles to a separate CSS page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue of event propagation.

[Here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing)'s my favorite reference site that has good visualizations for you about what's happening.

In short, your fix is to do two things.  Change your `onclick=` to say `onclick=valuesOnClick`, and add the following line in valuesOnClick:

```
element2.stopPropagation();
```

#### What's happening

Events bubble from the deepest div up to the topmost layer, until they get sent to the `<body>`.  So when you click inside a div that has a click event and is nested inside other divs, all the divs will get the event.  Calling `event.stopPropagation()` will make the bubbling stop.

But, by calling `valuesOnClick(this)` with your `onclick` event, you're actually losing all the event information.  Instead, just tell onclick to immediately call back to valuesOnClick.  I'd recommend renaming `element2` inside the function to be `event` (just for clarity), and then you can reference the calling element simply with `this`.  (You can reference the lowest element at which the event originated with `event.target`.)

Comment: Thnx for this answer.This is exactly wht i did:function createTree(list,container){
    if(list){
     for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var tempID = generateGuid();
      li.setAttribute('id',tempID);
      li.setAttribute('onclick','element2.stopPropagation();valuesOnClick()');

Comment: @AshishSood I'm surprised that worked.  I've only seen `stopPropagation()` called on the parameter passed into the callback.  But as long as you're happy with it - awesome.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using jquery, what are you using onclick attributo instead of $(element).click()?

The problem I think is that you're putting onclik listeners on elements an on it's children..so if you have a `<li>` with and `<ul>` child, and each of the `<ul>` `<li>` chlidren has onclick, if you click one of the last `<li>`, that is gonna trigger his onclik and the onclik of the first `<li>` (the first mentioned)

You need to stop propagation

Comment: m just an amateur web developer trying to figure out java script and jQuery and Thnx for the reply really helpfull in understanding the issue

Comment: @Ashish Sood good. I edited the reply because it was missing something.